# Django Model/Manager Dependency

Tags: django, django-models

When using a Custom Model Manager the way it is shown in the documentation and examples that I have found, the Custom Managers are placed in the same source file as the Model.

My models.py file has a base class with four sub-classes and the base class has several static methods to provide some common queries. I will need to add quite a few custom queries. I would prefer to put these in a Custom Model Manager that is a Base class for each of the subclasses Model Managers. I would also like to be able to separate the Model Managers into a separate source file called managers.py to make the code less messy.

The problem is that there is a cyclic dependency between the Models and Managers.

Is there a way to set the Manager to the "objects" variable by name instead of the actual Model Manager class? Or perhaps some other way to be able to put the code into the two separate files?

```
models.py

class MyBaseModelClass(models.Model):  (abstract)
    list_of_values (Many to Many Field)

class class SubclassA(MyBaseModelClass):
    objects = SubclassAManager()
    # list_of_values pulled from external system

class class SubclassB(MyBaseModelClass):
    objects = SubclassBManager()
    # list_of_values manually added by the user in the UI and stored in the DB

class class SubclassC(MyBaseModelClass):
    objects = SubclassCManager()
    # list_of_values derived from subclass fields and not stored in the DB

class class SubclassD(MyBaseModelClass):
    objects = SubclassDManager()
    # list_of_values derived from subclass fields and not stored in the DB


managers.py

class MyCustomBaseManager(models.Manager):
    # Does custom queries that do calculations and other data manipulations that are common to all of the 
    # Subclasses. Note that MyBaseModelClass can't have a Manager because it is Abstract.

class SubclassAManager(MyCustomBaseManager):

class SubclassBManager(MyCustomBaseManager):

class SubclassCManager(MyCustomBaseManager):

class SubclassDManager(MyCustomBaseManager):
```

Comment: What is the cyclic dependency? Your managers should not need to import your models

Comment: Maybe I am going about this the wrong way. 

In my working implementation I have static methods on the base class that loop through each of the subclasses and query the information I need. 

In most queries, I need to collect the instances from all four of the subclasses. My business logic can't know that they are different, but under the covers they acquire the values for a base class field differently. 

Adding some additional info into the model classes in the original post.